# Select2 multiple calls to ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a problem with the Select2 component in this code:

```js
$("#group_select_name").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a Group",
  allowClear: true,
  ajax: {
    type: "GET",
    url: "../contactGroup",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
          console.log("update 2")
          return {
            id: (obj.id),
            text: (obj.name)
          };
        })
      };
    },
  }
});
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to search for something using the search field, the component make multiple undesired AJAX requests to the server. In the console of the browser I see thousands of "update 2".

The version of Select is the `4.0.3`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the componente make a request for each key pressed. You can define a delay to start the request, like described in the official doc:

> By default, Select2 will trigger a new AJAX request whenever the user
>   changes their search term. You can set a time limit for debouncing
>   requests using the ajax.delay option.

https://select2.github.io/options.html#a-request-is-being-triggered-on-every-key-stroke-can-i-delay-th

```
$('select').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/example/api',
    delay: 250
  }
});
```

**[EDIT]**

Your `console.log` is inside the `map` function, that will be executed for each element in result after each request.

Comment: How to stop this Behaviour? I don't need this. Also the search function not works on the right way.

Comment: You can write your own `transport` using the `debounce` function of `underscore` library.

Comment: I've changed the ajax example to use a custom `transport`, look: https://jsfiddle.net/rogeriolino/s40uo4p1/